# Overloading >> using istream

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

So I am trying to overload the `>>` operator, but in this case I am getting a null terminated string in. How do I make the user only input enough characters that my dynamically allocated `char[]` named data and allocate it. I know there could be a way where I make a temp `char[]` with a size very big and use a for loop to copy them in, but I want to make it without making a very big `char[]`. I have this code for now but I know it doesn't work because of the length allowed in my class being passed in.

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, String346 & objIn) {
        using std::istream;

        is >> objIn.data;

        return is;
    }
```

Comment: You could get characters one at a time and check you have enough space before storing

Answer (score 2):

The C++ language contains no provision to technically bar the user to "only input enough characters" for your `char` array. There may be some operating system-specific resources available to you, such as limiting the maximum number of characters in a text entry field, but that's outside the scope of C++.

When reading from a `std::istream`, your code must be prepared to handle and deal with input that does not fit your criteria. Throw an exception, exit the program after printing an error message, or read up to the maximum number of characters you can accept and ignore the extra -- in whatever manner makes sense to you. It's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::istream::get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) has an overload that allows you to limit size of the input. You still need to deal with the remaining input one way or another though.